# Fatal error: Allowed memory size on php 5.6.3

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error, memory

initially good, but some time suddenly appear a message

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 36 bytes) in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\celebescomputer\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php
>   on line 234

at time save config on system-configuration

Comment: OP, hard to know the issue without more data about your setup. Edit and we can reopen if linked thread does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento comes with a default .`htaccess` file in the root directory that includes this configuration directive.

```
php_value memory_limit 256M

php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

OR

The php memory resource can be increased in the `php.ini`

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 256M
```